# SqlException : Incorrect syntax near '1'

Tags: c#, sql, unity-game-engine, prepared-statement

I am currently trying to implement SQL into a project with Unity3D. So far, I was able to do "normal" UPDATE, ADD, DELETE, DROP, ALTER, INSERT".

Trying to go a step further, I am trying to insert prepared statements, using this link as a [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Here is my code :

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Connection.connectionString)
sqlConnection.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(null, sqlConnection);
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO IngredientTypes (Name) VALUES (@name)";

SqlParameter nameParam = new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.Text, 155);
nameParam.Value = Name;
cmd.Parameters.Add(nameParam);

cmd.Prepare();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

My table looks like so :

```
CREATE TABLE IngredientTypes
(
    IngredientTypeID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(155)
);
```

I get this error :

> SQLException : Incorrect systax near '1'.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ErrorHandler (System.Object sender, Mono.Data.Tds. Protocol.TdsInternalErrorMessageEventArgs e)

Help please? Thank you in advance.. I can't find where I did wrong.

Comment: What is your `Name` variable set to?

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce that code quite a bit with no loss of function, and even some important improvements (for example, this will close the connection even if an exception is thrown):

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Connection.connectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO IngredientTypes (Name) VALUES (@name)",  sqlConnection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 155).Value = Name;
    sqlConnection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I'm not sure what's causing that exception in your existing code, though, because `1` is not used anywhere in that query. I *suspect* the problem has something to do with `SqlDbType.Text`, since that is **not** the correct type to use with a `VarChar` column, but it seems just as likely there's code somewhere we haven't seen yet that's changing your SQL command text.

Definitely the `Prepare()` method in your link is *not needed for Sql Server.* It's inherited here from `DbCommand`, where it's included because it's an important part of the API for some other databases, but Sql Server has handled this automatically for more than 10 years now.

Comment: Thanks for the last paragraph info. I tried something that I learned at school but with PHP... hehe. I removed the Prepare() method from my code and I didnt receive any error. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

SqlDbType.Text Is not the same as varchar.  I don’t believe Text types have a length you specify.

Comment: I tried NVarChar and Varchar. But the error I receive is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try below? Using the "using" structure is safer for sql connections by the way, the connection automatically closes when your process is done.

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Connection.connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO IngredientTypes (Name) VALUES (@name)", connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.Varchar, 155);
        command.Parameters["@name"].Value = Name; //make sure Name is string.

        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the using structure. Actually the code I pasted is inside an using, I just didnt mentioned it on the post. The error is still the same.. :/

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code exactly as it is and found no issue. Though there are few compilation errors (missing ; in line 1 and Name variable should be coming as parameter) but I am sure you know that. If you have posted your table structure and code exactly the same as you have in your project, then there is no problem in this code.